# Is there an exhaustive list of all the errors that can be triggered while Puppeteer web scraping + explanations?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, error-handling, puppeteer

I am trying to build a web scraper with Puppeteer `(Node.js==v19.4.0; Puppeteer==v9.2.0).`
The scraping of 1500 webpages is triggering the following errors:

```
- ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
- Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded
- ERR_TIMED_OUT
- ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
- ERR_ABORTED
- ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
- ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
- Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation
- ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
- ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
- ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
- ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
- ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE
- ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
- ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
- ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
```

I looked for the errors individually but could not find satisfying explanations of why these happen and how to solve the related issues. Moreover, I went to the Puppeteer documentation and could not find more.

I was wondering whether such a webpage https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html (List of all errors in Node.js) existed for Puppeteer triggered errors?

I thank you very much for your help.

- Marina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first answer gives good reasons for the errors and explanations. Here are possible solutions for some of the issues.

`Navigation timeout`: According to Puppeteer's documentation: https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.goto, the maximum navigation timeout is 30s, and maybe the target page in `page.goto` requires more time to load (not likely, but possible). Try disabling the timeout, i.e., setting it to `0`

```
page.goto(`https://your-webpage.com`,{timeout: 0});
```

It's very likely the Puppeteer execution context is destroyed as a result of previously triggered errors. So you need to figure out the possible culprit(s).

Regarding some of the other errors like: `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` or `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`, these could be caused by outdated cookies or browser caches. That is, the website being accessed may have moved to a different IP but your browser is getting the outdated address from the cached data. Try `clearing the browser cache and cookies`; you can retain the browser history though.

Regarding `SSL`/`HTTPS` related errors like: `ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`, `ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID`, etc. these could be due to using `self-signed certificates` on your localhost. Using the puppeteer option `ignoreHTTPErrors` could get rid of this family of errors. The below sample code shows how to use this option, try adapting to your own code.

```
   let browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: false,
            'ignoreHTTPSErrors': true
            args: ["--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
            
        });
```

If these tips don't solve the issues you could consider sharing part of the code which you think is faulty.

Best of luck,
Pete

Answer (score 0):

Most of errors are Chrome network errors, list of them you can find via chrome://network-errors/

Explanation for each case can be found [there](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:net/base/net_error_list.h)

Puppeteer errors from the list:

> Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded

That's error when navigation to webpage wasn't succeed after timeout. Example: Site wasn't opened after `page.goto` or after clicking on a link with redirect.

> Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation

That means that you context (page or frame) is not exist anymore. Possible reasons: page reload or redirect to another page, closing tab with context, etc.